# "ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'nativesdk-mono'"

Tags: linux, mono, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

trying to inherit mono in a recipe which has `BBCLASSEXTEND="nativesdk"`. But build is failing with  `"ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'nativesdk-mono'"`

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'nativesdk-mono' (but virtual:nativesdk:/....example.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it). Close matches
```

Comment: either move the BBCLASSEXTEND statement if you don't need the nativesdk package of the example.. or you extend the mono package by creating an bbappend file with the statement BBCLASSEXTEND="nativesdk" and fixing issues if they occour

Comment: Can you please give an example of bbappend for mono